# Как извлечь количество репостнувших на facebook с помощью facebook php api?

Tags: php, facebook

Я извлек лайкнувших данным способом:

```
<?php
  require_once __DIR__ . '/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
  $ACCESS_TOKEN = "EAAPMsX1FZCcwBAMoZBJcSvoZByUH1osyWMkcNiLdKQbfNxQzV7c75qiEHZCXtZB9XBpiiktbVCRhoZAfiZAoc9180oMnA7t01LmrfDFZCuO2ZCfzhqeeWfIVg8VchQXUTz6sTZBEBqZCXDWo2iYZAiqlpav4oZCG1ualiyjXZAWndgu6MeTwZDZD";
  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '1069487613148620',
    'app_secret' => '6d2009f84a43bccf600c3754eac71b5c',
    'default_access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
  ]);

  try {
    $response = $fb->sendRequest('GET', '/946879378758790_1070701743043219/shares', array('summary' => true), $ACCESS_TOKEN, 'eTag', 'v2.8');
  }
  catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
  catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }

  $likesEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
  $totalCount = $likesEdge->getTotalCount();
  echo "REPOSTS TOTAL: " . $totalCount;
?>
```

Подскажите, как сделать тоже самое с репостами.

Comment: Отформатируйте вопрос и появится больше желающих Вам помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  require_once __DIR__ . '/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

    //$ACCESS_TOKEN = "102688566892314|sYsTLEmbV9eGbUG7sE_4zSBGCHg";


   $ACCESS_TOKEN = "EAAPMsX1FZCcwBAMoZBJcSvoZByUH1osyWMkcNiLdKQbfNxQzV7c75qiEHZCXtZB9XBpiiktbVCRhoZAfiZAoc9180oMnA7t01LmrfDFZCuO2ZCfzhqeeWfIVg8VchQXUTz6sTZBEBqZCXDWo2iYZAiqlpav4oZCG1ualiyjXZAWndgu6MeTwZDZD";



    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '1069487613148620',
    'app_secret' => '6d2009f84a43bccf600c3754eac71b5c',
    'default_access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
    ]);

//$request = $fb->request('GET', '/363865183112_10154190067888113/likes?summary=true');
//203190063704_10154125012873705
try {
  $response = $fb->sendRequest('GET', '/946879378758790_1070701743043219/shares', array('summary' => true), $ACCESS_TOKEN, 'eTag', 'v2.8');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$likesEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
$totalCount = $likesEdge->getTotalCount();

echo "REPOSTS TOTAL: " . $totalCount;

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```